# puppet upgrade to 3.8 fails

Tags: postgresql, puppet

i am upgrading puppet from 3.3.2 to 3.8, while running the "puppet-enterprise-installer" i get the below error.... any ideas/pointers as to what it is?  I am suspecting this might be related to postgres but not 100% sure....There are no ports that are blocked on this instance...

Here is end part of the install log output

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-rbac" CONNECTION LIMIT -1]: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-rbac'] has failures: true
Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-rbac" ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'K4avh50pF8xoNMr87T7I']: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-rbac'] has failures: true
Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Database[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[Check for existence of db 'pe-activity']: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-activity'] has failures: true
postgresql::Server::Role[pe-classifier]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-classifier" NOREPLICATION]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-classifier]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-classifier]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-classifier" CONNECTION LIMIT -1]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-classifier]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-classifier]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-classifier" ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'Kz7SjzJQymr5fMS6W459']: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Database[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql_psql[Check for existence of db 'pe-rbac']: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Database[pe-rbac]/Exec[/opt/puppet/bin/createdb --port='5432' --owner='pe-postgres' --template=template0 --tablespace='pe-rbac'  'pe-rbac']: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Database[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql_psql[REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE "pe-rbac" FROM public]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Database[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql_psql[UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = false WHERE datname = 'pe-rbac']: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql_psql[CREATE ROLE "pe-rbac" ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'K4avh50pF8xoNMr87T7I' LOGIN NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB NOSUPERUSER  CONNECTION LIMIT -1]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-rbac" NOSUPERUSER]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-rbac" NOCREATEDB]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-rbac" NOCREATEROLE]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-rbac" LOGIN]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-rbac" INHERIT]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-rbac" NOREPLICATION]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-rbac" CONNECTION LIMIT -1]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-rbac" ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'K4avh50pF8xoNMr87T7I']: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_pNotice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Database[pe-activity]/Exec[/opt/puppet/bin/createdb --port='5432' --owner='pe-postgres' --template=template0 --tablespace='pe-activity'  'pe-activity']: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-activity'] has failures: true
Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Database[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE "pe-activity" FROM public]: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-activity'] has failures: true
Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Database[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = false WHERE datname = 'pe-activity']: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-activity'] has failures: true
Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[CREATE ROLE "pe-activity" ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'UHjfxGCAP5UT1XV1jLmC' LOGIN NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB NOSUPERUSER  CONNECTION LIMIT -1]: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-activity'] has failures: true
Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-activity" NOSUPERUSER]: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-activity'] has failures: true
Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-activity" NOCREATEDB]: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-activity'] has failures: true
Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-activity" NOCREATEROLE]: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-activity'] has failures: true
Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-activity" LOGIN]: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-activity'] has failures: true
Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-activity" INHERIT]: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-activity'] has failures: true
Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-activity" NOREPLICATION]: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-activity'] has failures: true
Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-activity" CONNECTION LIMIT -1]: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-activity'] has failures: true
Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-activity" ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'UHjfxGCAP5UT1XV1jLmC']: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-activity'] has failures: true
Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-classifier]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Database_grant[GRANT pe-classifier - ALL - pe-classifier]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Grant[database:GRANT pe-classifier - ALL - pe-classifier]/Pe_postgresql_psql[GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "pe-classifier" TO "pe-classifier"]: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-classifier'] has failures: true
Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Database_grant[GRANT pe-rbac - ALL - pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Grant[database:GRANT pe-rbac - ALL - pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql_psql[GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "pe-rbac" TO "pe-rbac"]: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-rbac'] has failures: true
ostgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Database[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[Check for existence of db 'pe-activity']: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Database[pe-activity]/Exec[/opt/puppet/bin/createdb --port='5432' --owner='pe-postgres' --template=template0 --tablespace='pe-activity'  'pe-activity']: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Database[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE "pe-activity" FROM public]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Database[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = false WHERE datname = 'pe-activity']: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[CREATE ROLE "pe-activity" ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'UHjfxGCAP5UT1XV1jLmC' LOGIN NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB NOSUPERUSER  CONNECTION LIMIT -1]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-activity" NOSUPERUSER]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-activity" NOCREATEDB]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-activity" NOCREATEROLE]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-activity" LOGIN]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-activity" INHERIT]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-activity" NOREPLICATION]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-activity" CONNECTION LIMIT -1]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "pe-activity" ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'UHjfxGCAP5UT1XV1jLmC']: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-classifier]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Database_grant[GRANT pe-classifier - ALL - pe-classifier]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Grant[database:GRANT pe-classifier - ALL - pe-classifier]/Pe_postgresql_psql[GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "pe-classifier" TO "pe-classifier"]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Database_grant[GRANT pe-rbac - ALL - pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Grant[database:GRANT pe-rbac - ALL - pe-rbac]/Pe_postgresql_psql[GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql_psql[CREATE EXTENSION citext;]: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-rbac'] has failures: true
Notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Database_grant[GRANT pe-activity - ALL - pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Grant[database:GRANT pe-activity - ALL - pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "pe-activity" TO "pe-activity"]: Dependency Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-activity'] has failures: true
Notice: Finished catalog run in 6.51 seconds
pe-rbac" TO "pe-rbac"]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql_psql[CREATE EXTENSION citext;]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Pe_postgresql::Server::Db[pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Database_grant[GRANT pe-activity - ALL - pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Grant[database:GRANT pe-activity - ALL - pe-activity]/Pe_postgresql_psql[GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "pe-activity" TO "pe-activity"]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
## Setting up the console...
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "puppetmaster.example.org" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "puppetmaster.example.org" (10.0.1.183) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tasks: TOP => configuration:export => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
!! ERROR: Rake task could not export classification.

=====================================================================================================================================================================================================
[root@puppetmaster puppet-enterprise-3.8.0-el-6-x86_64]#
```

Comment: The interesting part (i.e. the failing resource(s)) is missing.

Comment: @FelixFrank, what exactly do you mean by that and where would that be found at ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work.

As part of the upgrade, the installer shuts down everything, but it seems like we need to first shut down everything (all of the PE related services) and **then** run the installer.